# How do I sort a whole element based off of one piece of it?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a table with the general structure

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>
  <a href="http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/accel-world">Accel World</a>
  </td>
</tr
```

but with many more table rows, each having a td with an index and another td with an 'a element' with the title of a show and a place to find said show.

I end up sorting it, alphabetically based off the text content of the a element, the stuff inside the tag. I then sort all of those outside as an array and plug them back into the element. The problem is the href didn't move. I sorted the text Content but not the hyper reference link the text corresponds to.

How can I sort it to where the hyper reference corresponds to the text within-the title? Keep in mind, I can't sort it based off the href and plug it in because there are too many special cases which make it not work.

Here is my code so far, you can ignore the parseText as it is what generates the table.

```
function parseText(file, tableNumb, link) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', file, true);
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        var reg = /[^|(\r\n|\n|\r)]+/g;
        var regResponse = response.match(reg);
        var table = document.getElementById(tableNumb);
        var length = 0;
        var tIndex = 1; //get the length of the table to match number count
        var count = 0;
        var links = [];
        for(i = length; i < regResponse.length/2;i++){ 
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = tIndex;
            cell1.innerHTML = '<a href=\'' + regResponse[count+1] + '\'>' + regResponse[count] + '</a>';
            link[i] = regResponse[count];
            count++;
            count++;
            tIndex++;
          }
        sorted(link); //keep
    }
}



    }
    var sortList = document.getElementById("one");
    var link = sortList.getElementsByTagName("a");


    var sortList2 = document.getElementById("two");
    var link1 = sortList2.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var sortList3 = document.getElementById("three");
    var link2 = sortList3.getElementsByTagName('a');


parseText('Watched.txt', 'one', link);
parseText('Watching.txt', 'two', link1);
parseText('Dropped.txt', 'three', link2);

function sorted(sortList) {
    var sibling = [];


    for(i = 0; i < sortList.length; i++){
        sibling[i]=sortList[i].textContent;

    }

    function insensitive(s1, s2) {
      var s1lower = s1.toLowerCase();
      var s2lower = s2.toLowerCase();
      return s1lower > s2lower ? 1 : (s1lower < s2lower? -1 : 0);
    }
    sibling.sort(insensitive);

    for(var i = 0; i < sortList.length; i++){
        sortList[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue=sibling[i];


    }

    }
```

Here is some data from a table:

```
Attack on Titan|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/attack-on-titan
Durarara!!|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/durarara
Kyoukai no Kanata|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/beyond-the-boundary
Log Horizon|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/log-horizon
Mahou Shoujo Madoka Magica|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica
Mushishi|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/mushishi
Naruto|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/naruto
Neon Genesis Evangelion|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/neon-genesis-evangelion
Space Dandy|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/space-dandy
Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tengen-toppa-gurren-lagann
Ore Monogatari|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/my-love-story
Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Come wa Machigatteiru|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/yahari-ore-no-seishun-love-come-wa-machigatteiru
Diebuster|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/gunbuster-2
```

Comment: Is requirement to sort `tr` elements alphabetically comparing `tr` `a` child node text ?

Comment: I sort a elements based off the text content, alphabetically. so in this example the text content is "Accel World". The tr element is just the container. Really the a elements will just be moved around

Comment: `js` at Question not returning expected results ? Can include full `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is a prime example of when you should be using a framework. To do something like you want using say angular can be done with much less code and be more easily maintainable. With that being said, I quickly put together a fiddle using pure js to solve what I think you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/7sd6nwxq/2/

```
// given a url, return the responseText in a callback
function ajaxText(url, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = xhr.responseText;
            cb(null, response);
        }
    }
    xhr.onerror = function(err){
        cb(err);
    }
}

// convert text string into a list of items
function listFromText(text){
    var list = [];

    var reg = /[^|(\r\n|\n|\r)]+/g;
    var regResponse = text.match(reg);

    for(var i=0; i<regResponse.length; i+=2){
        list.push({
            title: regResponse[i],
            href: regResponse[i+1]
        });
    }

    return list;
}

// function for performing lower case sorting on items
function sorter(a, b){
    var s1lower = a.title.toLowerCase();
    var s2lower = b.title.toLowerCase();
    return s1lower > s2lower ? 1 : (s1lower < s2lower? -1 : 0);
}

// function for building the table html from a list
function buildTable(id, list){
    var table = document.getElementById(id);
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);

        cell.innerHTML = i;
        cell1.innerHTML = '<a href=\'' + list[i].href + '\'>' + list[i].title + '</a>';
    }
}

// get the text via ajax from a gist i created
ajaxText('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matt-way/90eb514ed8d897649be9/raw/538a7bbfd0f7406634190c3dac0984e6c2dcc532/ajaxtest.txt', function(err, resultText){
    // get the unsorted list
    var tableList = listFromText(resultText);
    // sort the list
    tableList.sort(sorter);
    // build the html from the sorted list
    buildTable('1', tableList);
});
```

Comment: I can't tell if it works. I tried implementing what you did with my ajax but its not working. What exactly did you think you did that fixed the issue?

Comment: Your question was very vague, so I am still not sure what your issue is (I made guesses as to what you were after). If you take one of your text files, and replace my dummy text with it (in the fiddle), you should be able to test it. Better yet, why not paste a portion of one of your text files in the question!

Comment: I added some data from a table. The "I ended up sorting" paragraph goes into detail what my problem was.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my fiddle to use some of the text you posted, which works fine. I think the problem you are having is trying to sort the html itself, while my code sorts the data first, before creating the table. Please read through my code as it is quite self explanatory.

Comment: I did, but aren't you sorting it based on the same sorting process for both the href and the title? It won't work using that because there are special cases, such as the links being all lower-case and the titles not.

Comment: I am sorting purely by the title after making it lower case.

Comment: any idea why my solution won't work? I'm trying to integrate ajax and it is not working. Specifically, tablelist is undefined. https://jsfiddle.net/7sd6nwxq/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98527/discussion-between-matt-way-and-actionon).